# How to emulate process of making photo in virtual box android emulator like on regular phone (Android x86)

Tags: android, camera, virtualbox, emulation, android-x86

Is it possible to do this? I need to open camera in emulator and make a photo, but by default emulator dont have access to real camera when i opened it there just a black empty interface.
I need to making photo like if i make this photo in real time on regular phone.

Put ready photo tap photo button and from the side it seems like im making photo normally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is possible to emulate both the front and back of the phone's cameras.

If you are using Android Studio, you can head over to `AVD Manager`, press the pencil (known as an *edit*) button beside the phone emulator on the left side, click `Show Advanced Settings`, and you should see the `Camera` section ([the image of the camera section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IdUq.png)), and choose the webcam option, or whatever that is relevant to your case.